# Confidence stats question

Tags: probability

In my textbook I was given the question:

Suppose that a popular hotel for vacationers in Orlando, Florida, has a total of 300 identical rooms. As many major airline companies do, this hotel has adopted an overbooking policy in an effort to maximize the usage of its available lodging capacity. Assume that each potential hotel customer holding a room reservation, independently of other customers, cancels the reservation or simply does not show up at the hotel on a given night with probability $0.15$. Find the largest number of room reservations that this hotel can book and still be at least $95\%$ sure that everyone who shows up at the hotel will have a room on a given night.

I can't work out whether this would involve binomial distribution or standard deviation, would anyone be able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed binomial: you want $n$ such that if $B$ is Bin(n,0.85) then $P(B>300) \leq 0.05$, but as close to $0.05$ as possible. You can get a rough estimate by just aligning the averages: that is, by taking $0.85n=300$. This gives $n=353$. At this point your desired $95\%$ would be around $50\%$, so this $n$ is too high, but not drastically so.

To get a better approximation, you can use the normal approximation to the binomial. Specifically, the normal approximation to $B$ is a normal distribution with mean $0.85n$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{n(0.15)(0.85)} \approx 0.36\sqrt{n}$.

So you introduce $Z=\frac{B-0.85n}{0.36\sqrt{n}}$, and take that to have a standard normal distribution. Then you want $\frac{300.5-0.85n}{0.36\sqrt{n}}$ to match up with the 0.05 upper tail of the standard normal distribution, which is at about 1.65. (The extra 0.5 is a "continuity correction", which for values this large is not really that important.) That is you want to solve $\frac{300.5-0.85n}{0.36\sqrt{n}}=1.65$ for $n$. There is a single solution to this equation, which you should know how to find. Round it to the nearest integer.

Now you can actually try this with the binomial distribution to check your answer. You'll want to use software like MATLAB rather than a calculator for this step. If you get something less than 0.05 for $P(B>300)$, then your answer is satisfactory, and you can try increasing it to see if you have the best one. If you get something greater than 0.05, then your answer is not satisfactory, and you should try decreasing it until it becomes satisfactory. Here $n$ will be so large that you should expect your normal approximation answer to be within $1$ of the binomial answer.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, how would this be checked using binomial distribution though. I can't work out what the parameters would be

Comment: @JeremyStephen As I said at the top, the "real" distribution you are interested in is $B$ with distribution $Bin(n,0.85)$. So once you have a candidate for $n$ you can compute $P(B>300)$ directly. Since $n$ is so big, this is hard to do with just a hand calculator, but it is easy to do with software.

Comment: So to calculate P(B>300) would you do 1-P(B<299), which would be the sum of P(B=0) + P(B=1).. etc

Comment: @JeremyStephen Here $n$ is close enough to $300$ that it is easier to compute $P(B=301)+P(B=302)+...+P(B=n)$. But this can be done quickly in software; for instance if your $n$ was $400$ you could use the MATLAB code binocdf(300,400,0.85,'upper')

Comment: I will download matlab, I got n to be 341 but just to check to check I am inputting the formula right, what value did you get if n was 400 for the probability?

Comment: @JeremyStephen With 400 I get 0.999999873646031. (You'll need to run "format long" to see this, otherwise it will show 1.0000). So 400 is too big :)

Comment: Okay, I worked it out using excel and got your value. Now using 341 as n the answer comes out as 0.04972. So does that mean 341 is an acceptable answer to the question?

Comment: @JeremyStephen That means 341 is acceptable (since the result is less than 0.05). To see whether it's the best, try the calculation again with 342.

Comment: That gives 0.06576209296105230, so it seems 341 is the best value. Thank you very much :)